# Styles from a ResourceDictionary is preventing all other functionality

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7.1

**UPDATE**: I moved the TextBox's style to the phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources tag and it behaves exactly the same way so it turns out that is not the fact the I am using a ResourceDictionary what is causing the problem but that there is something wrong with the way I am defining the style.

I just started playing around with ResourceDictionaries and I really like them but when I tried to use them on my application everything stopped working.

First the following TextBox:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" 
  Grid.Row="0"
  x:Name="Value" 
  InputScope="Number"
  TextAlignment="Right"
  TextChanged="OnValueTextChanged">
  <TextBox.Style>
      <StaticResource ResourceKey="InputTextBox" />
  </TextBox.Style>
 </TextBox>
```

**Update**: I have updated the ResourceDictionary per XAMeLi's answer and now I see the borders but it would seem as the TextBox does not have any background but, when I click on it nothing happens as if the TextBox is not even there. Then by pure luck I noticed that if I click on the bottom border the numeric keyboard would pop up as if the TextBox is too small or hiding below the border element. I tried modifying the TextBox height to no avail. This is driving me crazy.

Then the ListPickers are even worse:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker 
  Grid.Column="0" 
  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
  Grid.Row="1"
   x:Name="CategoriesPicker"
   HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerHeaderTemplate}"
   FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource CategoriesPickerTemplate}"
   ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly"
   BorderThickness="0"
   Padding="0"
   Margin="0"
   SelectionChanged="OnCategoriesPickerSelectionChanged">
   <toolkit:ListPicker.Style>
      <StaticResource ResourceKey="ListPickersStyle"/>
   </toolkit:ListPicker.Style>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

When the Style is in it won't even bind the data I'm giving to it.

The file with the ResourceDictionary looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit">
    <Style x:Name="InputTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-12"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="0 1">
                <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset=".3"/>
                <GradientStop Color="LightSlateGray" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Border
                            BorderThickness="2"   
                            Margin="15"
                            CornerRadius="3">
                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="0 1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="DarkGray"></GradientStop>
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="DarkGray"></GradientStop>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="LightSlateGray"></GradientStop>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                        <Border
                            BorderThickness="2"
                            CornerRadius="3">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1 1" EndPoint="1 0">
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Gray"></GradientStop>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="DarkGray"></GradientStop>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="DarkGray"></GradientStop>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>

                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Name="ListPickersStyle" TargetType="toolkit:ListPicker">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:ListPicker">
                    <Border 
                        BorderThickness="2"
                        Padding="0"
                        Margin="10"                        
                        CornerRadius="3"
                        Background="DarkGray">
                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="0 1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="DarkGray"></GradientStop>
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="DarkGray"></GradientStop>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="LightSlateGray"></GradientStop>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                        <Border BorderThickness="2"
                            CornerRadius="3">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1 1" EndPoint="1 0">
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Gray"></GradientStop>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="DarkGray"></GradientStop>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="DarkGray"></GradientStop>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                            <toolkit:ListPicker
                                BorderThickness="0"
                                Padding="0"
                                Margin="0">
                                <toolkit:ListPicker.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="0 1">
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="DarkGray"></GradientStop>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="DarkGray"></GradientStop>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="LightSlateGray"></GradientStop>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </toolkit:ListPicker.Background>
                            </toolkit:ListPicker>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Please, somebody explain to me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: When you create a copy of the Template used for the TextBox via Expression Blend, it includes a lot more detail than you have provided, have you stripped it down at all? Have you stripped down the Style for the ListPicker as well?

Comment: @PaulDiston: I didn't use Expression Blend. I originally wrote the XAML in the Main.xaml page and was working beautifully. When I read about Resource Dictionaries and since I had the same style in several controls I took it out, tried it and then it stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `ControlTemplate`s there are the controls them selves, i.e. control template for text box is holding a `TextBox`. This is not how control templates should be used. Use Blend or VS11 to extract the default style for each control (I'd recommend doing it in a new clean solution) and then change the visual appearance.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be on the right track. I have updated the Dictionary and the question since now there is a different problem, the TextBox seems to not be there.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference the style just like any other property, e.g.:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource InputTextBox}"/>
```

And try setting your Style first, then any settings you want to override, e.g.:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource InputTextBox}" TextAlignment="Right" />
```

Comment: Yes I can, but that does not change anything. The alignment and the InputScope properties are not having any effect.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [x:Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189012%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead of `x:Name` in `ResourceDictionary`:

> x:Key and x:Name are not identical concepts. x:Key is used exclusively
>   in resource dictionaries. x:Name is used for all areas of XAML. A
>   FindName call using a key value will not retrieve a keyed resource.
>   However, Silverlight 5 can use an x:Name (or Name) attribute as the
>   substitute resource key for a resource item if no x:Key exists on the
>   item.

and as soon as Windows Phone is far from Silverlight 5, you can not use x:Name in the dictionary.